# Power system analysis

Tags: three-phase, power-engineering

I really wish if someone can help me in these three questions:
three -phase balanced load has a 10 ohm resistance in each of its phases. The load is supplied by a 230/400 V three-phase source.
a) Calculate the power absorbed by the load if it is connected in wye (Y)? 
b) Calculate the power absorbed by the load if it is connected in delta?
c) What is the relation between these powers?

My attempt for these questions:
a) VLn,max = 230*sqrt(2) = 325.26
VLn= (325.26)/sqrt(3) = 187.79 
IL= VLn/R = 187.79 / 10 = 18.77 A
Ieff= IL/sqrt(2) = 13.27 
so P = sqrt(3)* Vload*Ieff*cos()
P= sqrt(3)* 230 * 13.27 *cos (0) = 5286.39 W ?

b) the same steps and P = 15934.86 W ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose for RMS values in AC circuits is to provide a method for performing calculations in the most direct way. There is no reason for converting back and forth between RMS and peak values.

I would take "Calculate the power absorbed by the load" to mean that the total power should be calculated, not the power per phase.